# Sound Professionals SP-BMC-1 - currently $9.99 reduced from $79.99

Tags: binaural, microphone

Anyone used a pair? Any opinions on quality?

I just ordered a pair, I'm thinking, even if they're not the best capsules I can inflict some serious punishment on them and get my money's worth for $9.99.. (hehehe)

Cheers,

Nick

Comment: Awesome! Glad you posted this, just ordered a pair :-) 

Comment: Damnit. They're sold out :(

Comment: Yeah sold out, Nick.  Looks like we're gonna have to wait until next sale.

Comment: Thanks, though! Is there a mailing list from them I can get on or what? Looks like there are some crazy good deals off that website sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, they have a mailing list you can subscribe to here: http://www.soundprofessionals.com/cgi-bin/gold/category/newsletter

Answer (score 1):

http://www.archive.org/details/nma2011-03-08.sp-bmc-1.flac16

Recording here with somebody using them to record this concert into an Edirol R-4. :)

Comment: Not bad for 10 bucks!

Comment: Yeah, I just ordered a pair too! Even with shipping im only paying £11. Great stuff thanks for the find!

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys,

I e-mailed them in hopes they had extras in stock and he found 15.

You can buy them! GO!!!

http://www.soundprofessionals.com/cgi-bin/gold/item/SP-BMC-1

http://www.soundprofessionals.com/cgi-bin/gold/category.cgi?category=110&item=SP-BMC-2-SS-BEIGE

Answer (score 0):

Dude awesome!! Thanks for posting!  I've been needing some mics! FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got there too late - they seem to be sold out...

Rats.  Thanks for the heads up, though!